# rails escaping html with jquery :remote => true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this piece of code in my .js.erb file:

```
$("#register_holder").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("layouts/register")) %>");
```

I will expect this to put the html in the register_holder div but instead it goes and puts this:

```
<div id="register_holder">    &lt;form accept-charset=UTF-8 action=/utilizator class=new_utilizator data-remote=true id=new_utilizator method=post&gt;&lt;div style=margin:0;padding:0;display:inline&gt;&lt;input name=utf8 type=hidden value=&amp;#x2713; /&gt;&lt;input name=authenticity_token type=hidden value=5tHgeGujhAMWGCQ9ioRK6Ra/hJgyFsBAm8uedCVZKP0= /&gt;div&gt;            &lt;ul&gt;                  &lt;li&gt;Email nu poate fi golli&gt;            ul&gt;        &lt;span&gt;          &lt;div class=field_with_errors&gt;&lt;input id=utilizator_email name=utilizator[email] placeholder=Scrieţi emailul dacă eşti interesant/ă size=30 type=email value= /&gt;div&gt;          &lt;input class=button id=utilizator_submit name=commit type=submit value=Anunţă-mă /&gt;        span&gt;form&gt;</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem with rails 3.1.0.rc2.  I believe it was impacting rails 3.0.x rcs also. Try upgrading your version of rails.  Here's some more information on the problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553

Comment: thanks man, I was going crazy searching the web for a solution